# Statically compile using Qt Creator

Tags: c++, linux, windows, qt, qt-creator

I've seen this asked many times, but with no real concrete answer. How do I compile my Qt Creator project with statically linked libraries?

My project is really simple. It's just a calculator, so I really don't think it needs to link much stuff.

My CMakeLists.txt file (there really isn't any change to this file, it's just the auto-generated one by Qt Creator):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(Calculator VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)

set(PROJECT_SOURCES
        main.cpp
        calculator.cpp
        calculator.h
        calculator.ui
)

if(${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} GREATER_EQUAL 6)
    qt_add_executable(Calculator
        MANUAL_FINALIZATION
        ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
    )
# Define target properties for Android with Qt 6 as:
#    set_property(TARGET Calculator APPEND PROPERTY QT_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR
#                 ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android)
# For more information, see https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt-add-executable.html#target-creation
else()
    if(ANDROID)
        add_library(Calculator SHARED
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
# Define properties for Android with Qt 5 after find_package() calls as:
#    set(ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android")
    else()
        add_executable(Calculator
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
    endif()
endif()

target_link_libraries(Calculator PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets)

set_target_properties(Calculator PROPERTIES
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER my.example.com
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)

if(QT_VERSION_MAJOR EQUAL 6)
    qt_finalize_executable(Calculator)
endif()
```

If you also want the entire project, [here it is](https://gitlab.com/Andy3153/atestat_informatica)

If this is even important to mention, I want to build two static executables, one for Linux and one for Windows. What do I need to add to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You have to first build the static libraries. Qt doesn't (or at least didn't, last I checked) distribute static libraries. Be prepared for an exercise when doing this for Windows. There's a Wiki, but it's flawed.

Also, note that using static Qt libraries is covered under a more restrictive license. You'll have to check Qt's site for details on this.